# How to create an angular modal to add deposits to a client panel app?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a pop up modal that will let a user add a deposit to a clients account. I am getting an error saying that "deposit.amount" isn't a known property of deposit-modal...so apparently I don't know how to define properties because I thought that I had.

Also, I would like the deposit to affect the balance which I haven't even looked at yet but will be trying to figure out next.

I'm sorry this is such a noob question...I am doing everything I can to learn angular as quickly as possible...I've got two angular courses to finish on Udemy as well as a physical book on it's way that I'm gonna start reading every night. But in the meantime...any help or advice you could share would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much.

Here are my files:

**deposit-modal** <- the modal
controller:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Deposit } from '../../../models/Deposit';


@Component({
    selector: 'deposit-modal',
    templateUrl: './deposit-modal.html',
  })

export class DepositModal {
    @Input() deposit: Deposit;
    @Output() close = new EventEmitter<Object>();

    constructor() {
        this.deposit.amount = 0;
        this.deposit.date = new Date();
    }

    ngOnInit() {


    }

    ok() {
        this.close.emit(this.deposit);
    }

    cancel() {
        this.close.emit(null);
    }
}
```

template:

```
<div>
    Add Deposit
    <input type="number" (change)="deposit.amount = $event.target.value;"/>
    <button type="button" (click)="ok()">OK</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**client-details** <- the parent
controller:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientService } from '../../services/client.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { DepositModal } from './deposit-modal/deposit-modal';

import { Client } from '../../models/Client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client-details',
  templateUrl: './client-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-details.component.css']
})
export class ClientDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  client: Client;
  hasBalance: boolean = false;
  showBalanceUpdateInput: boolean = false;
  deposits: Array<Object>;
  amount = 0;
  showIt: boolean = false;

  showModal() {
    this.showIt = true;
  }

  closeModal(deposit: Object) {
    this.showIt = false;
    if (deposit)
    this.deposits.push(deposit);
  }


  constructor(
    private clientService: ClientService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get id from url
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    // Cet client
    this.clientService.getClient(this.id).subscribe(client => {
      if(client != null) {
        if(client.balance > 0) {
          this.hasBalance = true;
        }
      }
      this.client = client;
    });
  }

  updateBalance(id: string) {
    this.clientService.updateClient(this.client);
    this.flashMessage.show('Balance Updated', {
      cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 4000
    });
  }

  onDeleteClick() {
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      this.clientService.deleteClient(this.client);
      this.flashMessage.show('Client Removed', {
        cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 4000
      });
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }

}
```

template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a routerLink="/" class="btn btn-link">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></i> Back to Dashboard
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <a routerLink="/client/edit/{{ id }}" class="btn btn-warning m-1 rounded">
            Edit
        </a>
          <a routerLink="/client/history/{{ id }}" class="btn btn-dark m-1 rounded">
          Deposit & Withdrawal History
      </a>
        <button (click)="onDeleteClick()" class="btn btn-danger m-1 rounded">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="client" class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h3 class="d-inline">{{ client.firstName }} {{ client.lastName }}</h3>
    <button type="button" (click)="showModal()" class="btn btn-success m-1 rounded d-inline pull-right">
     Add Deposit
    </button>
    <deposit-modal *ngIf="showIt" [deposit.amount]="amount" (close)="closeModal($event)"></deposit-modal>
  <a routerLink="/client/history/{{ id }}" class="btn btn-success m-1 rounded d-inline pull-right">
    Add Withdrawal
 </a>
</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cold-md-8 col-sm-6">
          <h4>Client ID: {{ client.id }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="cold-md-8 col-sm-6">
          <h5 class="pull-right">Current Balance: 
            <span
              [class.text-danger]="hasBalance"
              [class.text-success]="!hasBalance">
              {{ client.balance | currency: 'USD':'symbol' }}
            </span>
            <small>
              <a (click)="showBalanceUpdateInput = !showBalanceUpdateInput">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
              </a>
            </small>
          </h5>
          <div class="clearfix">
            <form *ngIf="showBalanceUpdateInput" (submit)="updateBalance()">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="balance" class="form-control ml-auto" style="max-width: 100px;" [(ngModel)]="client.balance">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-1">Update</button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Contact Email: {{ client.email }}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Contact Phone: {{ client.phone }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Client <- client model

```
import { Deposit } from './Deposit';

export interface Client {
    id?: string;
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
    email?: string;
    phone?: string;
    balance?: number;
    deposits?: Array<Deposit>
}
```

Deposit <- deposit model

```
export interface Deposit {
    id?: string;
    amount: number;
    date: Date;
}
```

Comment: its not good use the constructor to give values and less to a propertie that is an input -in constructor is null the object so, Angular give you an error. If you want to give a value by defect in a input use `@Input() deposit: Deposit={amount:0,deposit.date:new Date()}`

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that but I still can't pass the value from the modal input to the parent component.
The error is here: 

`<deposit-modal *ngIf="showIt"
    [deposit.amount]="amount" 
    (close)="closeModal($event)"></deposit-modal>`

It's saying that deposit.amount isn't a known property of client-modal.

Comment: A very nice solution I can think of is using Angular Material. It has a way to create a dialog and pass data to and from it. Check it out: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: I'd rather not create a dependency just for a single component.

Also, I actually got that solved...I'm not longer getting any errors but the data still isn't being passed... :(

Comment: really, as your `@Input()`is an object, you needn't pass the value -it's change automatically- I think that's the problem is when you define `deposits` in client, must be `deposits: Array<Object>=[]`. See that you need create as empty array (when que equal to []) else the value is null and you can not make a "push"